# Select a value from a table and use it to update a field of the same table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting some time data in a 12 hour format and i want to convert from 12 hour to 24 hour.This is the script i wrote that uses mysqli.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "qplat";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select the_time from r_data where transaction_type = 'send'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $id = 8980;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $new_id = $id++;
        $new_time = $row["the_time"];
        echo "the time is: " . $row["the_time"].'<br/>';
        $time = date("Hi", strtotime("$new_time"));
        $sql2 = "update r_data set 24_hour_time = '$time' where transaction_type = 'send' and id = $new_id";
        $conn->query($sql2);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The script updates the column `24_hour_time` with one time only leaving out all the other rows.

Can this be done using one table or will i have to insert into a different table then move the data back?.

Comment: Store time in just one column. You can format this time to different formats in the output with date() function

Comment: That's not an option for me. I need the 24 hour format to reside in its own column.

Comment: Why do you need the 24 hour format? What about use mysql function date_format in selects?

Comment: The data is from awkward sources so i am using php to clean it up.The time format at time might be really messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve the problem you are having using codeigniter like this

```
public function up(){
    $query = $this->db->query("select id,the_time from r_data where transaction_type = 'send'");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
    $id = $row->id;
    $new_time = $row->the_time;
    $time = date("Hi", strtotime("$new_time"));
    $data = array(
               '24_hour_time' => $time
            );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('r_data', $data); 
    }
    }
```